# Protection and filter on USB Power Lane device

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, protection, usb-device

Struggling finding good information, I would like to know which protections should be  on a USB device ?
The device is custom battery charger pcb ([using MP2607 from MPS](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp2607.html)) which should be plugged on AC adapter (which will not be supplied with the device).

I guess it should have least ESD protection, but there shouldn't be any overvoltage, because it is not connected to the power grid.

If you have good links or good information, I would really appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic protection for USB interface](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/basic-protection-for-usb-interface)

Comment: Thanks you. It only answer partially (only about ESD), but does my application need more protection on the Vbus line ?!